# I have an order_id which is no longer being generated-can not find issues with my create method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building an E-commerce site on rails (I somehow convinced myself it was a good challenge haha) and am now having an issue where the button "edit/confirm order" which would appear once a user clicks on 'add to cart' isno longer appearing, and when I use raise it shows that an order_id is no longer being saved. I can't find issues with my create method why that would be the case

```
def create
    if params[:order_sauce][:order_id].blank?
      order = Order.create(state: 'pending')
      session[:order_id] = order.id
      order_sauce = OrderSauce.new(order_sauce_params)
      order_sauce.order = order
      order_sauce.save
    else
      OrderSauce.create(order_sauce_params)
    end
   redirect_back(fallback_location: order_sauces_path, notice: "succesfully added to cart")

  end

def order_sauce_params
    params.require(:order_sauce).permit(:sauce_id, :quantity, :order_id)
  end
```

It seems like an order_id is no longer being generated, evident by;

```
<% if session[:order_id] %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit/Confirm Order', edit_order_path(session[:order_id]), class: "checkout" %>
        <% end %>
```

no longer returning anything

Comment: Some thoughts: Does order = Order.create(state: 'pending') work? If not (and this was my code) I'd check if validations for Order have changed recently. Have you changed anything about how sessions / cookies work recently? The else section in `def create` does not set `session[:order_id]`, could this be an issue?

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, it was an issue with my Validations! I need to specify the validations using on: :updates, as apposed to simply validates :variable, presence: true :) Cheers for the help!